# Airflow not respecting pool size?

Tags: airflow, pool

Using airflow backfill with LocalExecutor, the pool available slots seem to be ignored. Eg below. I know this has been raised a few years ago, but is this still an issue?

```
Pool    Slots   Used Slots  Queued Slots
    workerpool0 3   0   0
    workerpool2 3   12  0
```

Tried restarting webserver,scheduler.

Defining the pool in a BashOperator.

```
 BashOperator(
        task_id='sleep.%d'%i,
        bash_command='sleep %d'%(i+5),
        retries=3,
        pool='workerpool2',
        dag=dag)
```

I expect the pool size to be 3 but it is actually assigning 12 jobs as above?

Comment: could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771847/airflow-pool-used-slots-is-greater-than-slots-limit

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://%20https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=pool#pools)

> Pools are not thread-safe , in case of more than one scheduler in
> localExecutor Mode you can’t ensure the non-scheduling of task even if
> the pool is full.

Comment: I suppose this is about to change with the HA Scheduler. We might see an enhancement in how this tasks are managed, since it is the metadata database who holds the state instead of the different schedulers